# Read first file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, file, openexr

I'm trying to make a script that iterates through folders in a directory and saves the very first one in the folder to a variable. I'm trying to do this because I have folders in a directory with hundreads of .exr files but I only need the first file in the folder to be saved to the directory. I can get it to print out all the files in each folder but thats a bit too much info than I need. Is there an easy way to do this using something like os.walk? This is what I'm working with so far

```py
import os
    
def main():

    dirName = r"F:\FOLDERNAME"

    #Get the List of all files in the directory tree at given path
    listOfFiles = getListOfFiles(dirName)

    #Print the files
    for elem in listOfFiles:
    
        print(elem)

if __name__ =='__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks yall!

Comment: First by what criteria? Alphabetical name, age, file length?

Comment: If you only want the first one, use `listOfFiles[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you already:

> can get it to print out all the files in each folder

And you only want :

> the very first one

Then all you need is something like:

```py
first_file = list_of_files[0]
```

Looks like you're still learning the very basics of coding. I suggest looking up lessons/tutorials on lists, list indexing, and iterables.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `os.walk()`, it returns a list of files in each directory. You can print the first one.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dirName):
    if files:
        print(os.path.join(root, files[0]))
```